# validates_confirmation_of :password does not work [ruby 4.2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

`validates_confirmation_of :password` does not work when I submitted my form. Even if the password confirmation is not the same, the user is signed up.

I wrote the same thing that the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). during my research , I did not found anything that explain that.

Do you know what is happening and how can I solve it?

Here is my code:

My view:

```
    <%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.label :Prénom %> :

    <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control" %><br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.label :Nom %> :

    <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control" %><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
  <%= f.label :Pseudo %> :
  <%= f.text_field :user_name, class: "form-control"%><br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.label :Email %> :
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.label :Mot_de_passe %> :
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %><br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
  <%= f.label :Confirmation_mot_de_passe %> :
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %><br />
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.label :Club_favori %> :
  <%=f.select(:club) do%>
  <%= options_from_collection_for_select(Club.all,:id ,:name) %>
    <% end %>

  <br>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

My model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_merit
has_secure_password
has_many :comments

validates_length_of :password, minimum: 5, too_short: 'please enter at least 5 characters', on: :create
validates_presence_of   :user_name, :message => 'Vous devez remplir tout les champs.', on: :create
validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, :case_sensitive => false, :message => "Ce pseudo n'est pas disponible.", on: :create
validates_confirmation_of :password, on: :create
end
```

My controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def create  
  @user = User.new(user_params) 
  if @user.save 
    @user.add_badge(1)
    session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    redirect_to '/feed' 
  else 
    redirect_to '/signup', flash: {error_message: @user.errors}
  end 
end
private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit( :user_name, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :sash, :club)
  end 


  def new
    @user = User.new
    @clubs =Club.all
  end



end
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you also add the code where you create the user? Thanks!

Comment: @amrdruid I edited the post to add my controller.

Comment: I guess you you need to allow :password_confirmation in user_params.

Comment: Yes thanks, It works Perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You override your current `@user` when you enter your form.

Just change:

```
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```